# javascript not being executed in firefox. Ok in chrome

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a problem running this code in firefox. It's ok in chrome but there is a problem with firefox in that it won't run. When it should be executed, the browser does nothing and stays at the home screen. These are the methods that make the code stop being executed

```
function muteAudio(){
 backMus.volume -= 0.01;
 var voldown=setTimeout("muteAudio()", 20);
 if (backMus.volume <= 0.02){
     clearTimeout(voldown);
     backMus.muted = true;
 }
}
```

Any ideas would be gratefully received,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backMus` is an id of some element and you didn't define this variable explicitly, do you?

```
var backMus = document.getElementById('backMus');
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused about this. You're right. backMus DID need to be defined. The solution mgraph suggested did seem to make a difference but I have gone over it again and changed it back to how it was and on second check it didn't. I must have done something different that I didn't realise. Must work on this code more. Thanks for your help. It's fully functional now where after the first solution it was only half solved.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var voldown=setTimeout(function(){muteAudio()}, 20);
```

Comment: This only may change visibility of some variables, which is the same for Chrome and Firefox.